# My data is of the form *_*. I would like to apply a condition clause to it. IF(A1 = *_*,1,0). Doesn't work. Any other way to do it?

Tags: excel

My data is of the form *_* (for e.g., Normal_abcd_2_80_1)
. I would like to apply a condition clause to it. `IF(A1 = *_*_*_*_*,1,0)`. Doesn't work. Any other way to do it?

Comment: Just by default, you sinply validate to have at least 4 underscores which can be done with: `=IF((LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","")))>3,1,0)`... while just `"____"` also would satify this... however: having a searchterm like `"*_*_*_*_*"` would also be satified by just 4 folowing underscores ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula for only 4 `_` (and not more or less) saperated by other characters:

```
=IF(OR(ISERROR(FIND("_",A1,FIND("_",A1,FIND("_",A1,FIND("_",A1,1)+2)+2)+2)),NOT(ISERROR(FIND("_",A1,(FIND("_",A1,FIND("_",A1,FIND("_",A1,FIND("_",A1,1)+2)+2)+2)+2))))),0,1)
```

[image: Find formatted string]

And if you want more `_`, simply add them in the nested `FIND`.
However, this will not handle multiple `_` in a row, as can be seen in  cell `B5` 
above.

**----------------**

Here is a much more tedious but more precise way. I'll explain it using 10 helper columns, but you can also pack them all into one very-long-and-non-readable formula. The Idea is to slice the string to 10 parts, and check each part separately, and then see if all checks are correct. So here it is column by column:

1. Is the string not starting with `_`? `=NOT(LEFT($A2,1)="_")`
2. where is the first `_`? `=FIND("_",$A2,1)`
3. Is the next charachter after the first `_` is not `_`? `NOT(MID($A2,D2+1,1)="_")`
4. where is the next `_`? `FIND("_",$A2,D2+2)`
5. Is the next charachter after the next `_` is not `_`? `NOT(MID($A2,F2+1,1)="_")`
6. where is the next `_`? `FIND("_",$A2,F2+2)`
7. Is the next charachter after the next `_` is not `_`? `NOT(MID($A2,H2+1,1)="_")`
8. where is the next `_`? `FIND("_",$A2,H2+2)`
9. Is the next charachter after the next `_` is not `_`? `NOT(MID($A2,J2+1,1)="_")`
10. Is there any other `_`? `FIND("_",$A2,J2+2)`

[image: Using 10 helper columns]

Then you use the formula to test if all the 10 checks are correct:

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(AND(B2,C2,D2,E2,F2,G2,H2,I2,J2,ISERROR(K2)))),IF(AND(B2,C2,D2,E2,F2,G2,H2,I2,J2,ISERROR(K2)),1,0),0)
```

Now, instead of using 10 columns you can replace each cell reference in the above formula with the formula that written in it. I just thought it will be more clear this way ;)